# Energy of a relativist electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electrons, relativity

I need to find a way to obtain $E = mc^2(\gamma -1)$

by starting with :

$E = mc \cdot p = mc \cdot v \cdot \gamma$

with $ \gamma = \frac {1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Comment: All the equations in your post appear to be incorrect (apart from gamma's definition). Could you clarify what you mean? Perhaps you mean E to be the kinetic energy?

Comment: The correct starting point is $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$, so $E = \sqrt{p^2c^2 + m^2c^4}$ and you do it by using a binomial expansion and neglecting second order terms.

Comment: Indeed I meant the kinetic energy 

I wanted to show it with K = E - E0  with E0 = mc² and finding $E=mc^2\gamma$ with the method above.

But here I must find the expression by starting with $K = c\cdot p - mc^2$